# What kind of android widget should I use for making multiple choice answers for questions?

Tags: android

I am creating an android application and would like to set up my activity to have a question with multiple answers that they could chose from.  I was thinking radio buttons but I'm sure there is something more appropriate for this task.  Example

```
        Question
```

Answer1[x]    Answer2[x]   Answer3[x]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `CheckBox` if the user can select multiple options.

`RadioButton`is for when the user can only select one option.

As for layout:

It really depends, there are a lot of possible solutions, one possibility is:

```
<!--not all attributes are included,such as width and height, you have to add them-->
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView />
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal">  <!--contains options-->
        <CheckBox /> <CheckBox/> <CheckBox />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you suggest a LayOut I should use?

Answer (score 3):

Use `TextView` for the question and `ListView` with multiple choices for the answers below

```
ListView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
```